# A clean an sharp processing of a finite signal

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

It is known that the Fourier transform makes a signal decompose to some basic ones.

I am wondering to know, by some real and concrete examples,  how the Fourier transform makes processing on finite (discrete signals).
It is great to have some **real signal(s)**   whose representation (by Fourier transform)  obviously illustrate some (capable)  important information.  What **observable** information is extracted by Fourier coefficients?

Comment: For instance, if you take an audio waveform, then its Fourier transform will reveal the magnitude of its frequencies! In practice, this is usually done using the [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) for real-time computation :)

This means you can separate the signal into its frequencies, then separate the individual frequencies or perform all sorts of analysis, with a convenient organization of the signal in terms of its frequencies.

Comment: EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to recover a low-frequency signal $X$ from its noisy-perturbed version $X+w$ (where $w$ is noise). Sometimes we know that our noise was predominantly high-frequency noise. This means, that if we take the FFT of our signal, we can separate the low-frequency info (mostly $X$) from the high-frequency info (mostly $w$), to recover a pretty reasonable approximation of $X$ (implemented by performing inverse FFT on the low-frequency part of FFT($X+w$) )

Comment: Any example of finite discrete signal $x[n]$ where $n=0,1,2,\cdots k$?

Comment: This question might be better posed over at https://dsp.stackexchange.com where practitioners deal with this on a daily basis.  For example in digital communications the FFT of a signal (or FFT of a signal passed through a non-linearity) can be used to find spectral peaks used to estimate and track symbol rate and/or estimate and track carrier frequency offset.  The 0 Hz bin of the FFT can be used to track and remove DC offset from the signal.  The presence of spurs throughout the FFT indicate intermodulation products that usually induced by clipping (overdriving a receiver amplifier)

Comment: @AliBagheri Yeah, that example above works when both $X$ and $w$ are finite discrete signals of the same length $k$, (also FFT is really the DFT in that case).